# How to switch user instead of using uid?

Tags: exploit, privilege-escalation

In some methods of privilege escalation, if you want to be the `root` user, you write like this:

```
setuid(0);
setgid(0);
```

And this is because the `uid` and `gid` of the `root` user is `0`

```
id root

uid=0 (root) gid=0 (root) groups=0 (root)
```

But imagine creating another root user like this:

```
useradd -ou 0 test -g 50

id test

uid=0(root) gid=50(ftp) group=50(ftp)
```

As you know, we have another `root` user named `test` who has its own home (`/home/test`)

Now, if I `privilege escalation` again,

```
setuid(0);
setgid(50);
```

instead of being a `test` user, I will become root again but this time I am member of `ftp` group too, so is there a way to become a `test` user?

For example, is there any method like this:

```
setuser(test);
setgroup(ftp);
```

Or any ideas?

Comment: Users don't exist. The kernel only knows about uids and gids. The link between uids and usernames is entirely userspace. See [`getpwname` and `getpwid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Your comment is actually a good answer. I'd suggest you to convert it to an answer.